# Nginx An error occurred. Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable

Tags: php, nginx

I can not access any php files. I have treid to change fastcgi_pass to 127.0.0.1:9000 but that does not work either. I have looked at others with similar issues but nothing worked. This is the error message that I get: http://159.65.94.68/phpinfo.php

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
```

}

My Nginx error log is

```
2019/02/15 13:06:28 [error] 14208#14208: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "159.65.94.68"
2019/02/15 13:06:33 [crit] 14208#14208: *4 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 3.94.249.110, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1", $upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "159.65.94.68"
```

How do I fix this permission issue?

Comment: connect() to **unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock** failed (13: **Permission denied**)

Comment: Is the fpm running?

Comment: yes fpm is running

Comment: The error is obvious: permission of socket is incorrect: The solution is configuring `listener.owner` and `listener.user`: [https://serverfault.com/a/996685/544759](https://serverfault.com/a/996685/544759)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it and created a tutorial for it for future references since all the old onces only work for nginx 1.13 and lower but not 1.15+

https://hostup.org/blog/install-wordpress-on-latest-nginx-mainline-version/